# I don't see "Embedded Binaries" and "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" sections in Target/General

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to embed new framework, and I've been told that I have to add to  "Embedded Binaries" and "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" sections in Target/General. But what I see is "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content". I have added my framework to the following section, but what I get is a crash with the following message:

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ApiGatewayMac.framework/ApiGatewayMac
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/59E7EF3F-9BA7-46D9-B74C-5276C4089DF1/buda.app/buda
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/59E7EF3F-9BA7-46D9-B74C-5276C4089DF1/buda.app/Frameworks/ApiGatewayMac.framework/ApiGatewayMac: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/59E7EF3F-9BA7-46D9-B74C-5276C4089DF1/buda.app/Frameworks/ApiGatewayMac.framework/ApiGatewayMac'
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/59E7EF3F-9BA7-46D9-B74C-5276C4089DF1/buda.app/Frameworks/ApiGatewayMac.framework/ApiGatewayMac: stat() failed with errno=25

Is there a setting where I can get the General tab to show the two sections?